# How to share an ignite instance among jetty webapps

Tags: ignite

The docs state:

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/startup/servlet/ServletStartup.html

> Servlet-based startup may be used in any web container like Tomcat,
>   Jetty and etc. Depending on the way this startup is deployed the
>   Ignite instance can be accessed by either all web applications or by
>   only one. See web container class loading architecture:

But then points to a dead link regarding Jetty.

I'm using Jetty. How would this be done (sharing the ignite instance among all web applications)?

Comment: Looks like you provided a wrong link. Can you please check?

Comment: @ValentinKulichenko https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/startup/servlet/ServletStartup.html contains incorrect link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link to Jetty classloading](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jetty-classloading.html)

[Link to Ignite web configuration](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/web-session-clustering)

The latter describes web session clustering but you don't have to enable that to use Ignite. I think these docs should cover your case.

To share Ignite instance between web apps, you will need:

- Put Ignite libraries into server's main lib/ directory, and not under your web app directory
- Instantiate Ignite using Jetty API, as per [the documentation that you referenced](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/startup/servlet/ServletStartup.html)

code:

```
Server service = new Server();
service.addListener("localhost:8090");
ServletHttpContext ctx = (ServletHttpContext)service.getContext("/");
    ServletHolder servlet = ctx.addServlet("Ignite", "/IgniteStartup",
         "org.apache.ignite.startup.servlet.ServletStartup");
    servlet.setInitParameter("cfgFilePath", "config/default-config.xml");
servlet.setInitOrder(1);
servlet.start();
```

This assumes you are starting Jetty programmatically, i.e. [with your own code](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/quick-start-configure.html). Your mileage may vary if you don't.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps I'm missing something obvious but I still don't see it - nothing in these docs is explaining how an ignite instance (singleton) can be shared among all web applications in a Jetty server.

Comment: So when the mentioned servlet starts, how is the ignite instance accessed? `Ignition.ignite()`? How would that same ignite instance be referenced within another servlet, same method or annotations? Would all servlets sharing the same ignite instance have to use `org.apache.ignite.startup.servlet.ServletStartup` as a starting point and just use `Ignition.ignite()` in each?

Comment: @ReedSandberg Yes, the same instance (by name, or absense of thereof) will be available for all web apps. You don't have to initialize `ServletStartup` more than once.

Comment: Will the ignite instance be available for servlets started and (re)deployed via war auto-deployment? I understand `ServletStartup` cannot be deployed as a war to share the ignite instance, but assuming your code above, can other war webapps then access the same instance simply by `Ignition.ignite()`?

Comment: To answer my own question above, yes this can work sharing ignite between managed, auto-deployed war webapps, but you have to put Ignite classes in a top-level (shared) classloader like `WebAppContext.addSystemClasses(server, "org.apache.ignite.*");`. Otherwise, since each war webapp has its own classloader you get casting errors.